# Cylinders of two identical gas composites

Tags: homework-and-exercises, ideal-gas

[image]

I think the answer is B because gas pressure only changes when the temperature is changed and the volume does not change since this element did not change. The physics concept that is in regard is concerning the changes of pressure and volume.

Comment: Remember the ideal gas law, $PV=nRT$. That will easily give you the answer

Comment: Love the fact that there are two different answers labeled "B"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jim But as cylinder A has twice as much gas as B,   $$n_{a}= 2n_{b}$$

By $$PV=nRT$$ ,
$$ T_{A}= \frac{T_{B}}{2} $$

$$T_{A} < T_{B} $$